# Cannot Utilize Object - java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java

I am attempting to utilize a class which uses three other classes as data fields. Unfortunately, attempting to get the values of the nested objects does not seem to function.

This is the main program used to test the classes:

```
public class EmployeeTest
{
public static void main( String [] args )
    {
    String name1 = "John";
    String name2 = "Smith";
    String street = "12 Street";
    String state = "MA";
    String city = "Boston";
    String zip = "50312";
    int day = 12;
    int month = 12;
    int year = 2001;
    Employee employee1 = new Employee( name1, name2, street, city, state, zip, month, day, year );

    System.out.println("Employee's name is " + employee1.GetName1());
    }
}
```

This is the class of the object created:

```
public class Employee
{
private Name name;
private Address address;
private Date date;
// define data fields

public Employee( String name1, String name2, String street, String city, String state, String zip , int month, int day, int year)
    {
    Name name = new Name( name1 , name2 );
    Address address = new Address( street, city, state, zip);
    Date date = new Date();
    date.setDate( month , day, year );
    }
// constructor

public String GetName1()
    {
    String name1 = name.GetFirstName();
    return name1;
    }
// first name getter

public String GetName2()
    {
    String name2 = name.GetLastName();
    return name2;
    }

public String GetStreetName()
    {
    String street = address.GetStreet();
    return street;
    }
// street getter

public String GetCityName()
    {
    String city = address.GetCity();
    return city;
    }
// street getter

public String GetStateName()
    {
    String state = address.GetState();
    return state;
    }
// street getter

public String GetZipCode()
    {
    String zip = address.GetZip();
    return zip;
    }
// street getter

public String GetDate()
    {
    String time = date.getDateString();
    return time;
    }
}
```

This is the class which may be the source of the null exception:

```
public class Name
{
private String FirstName;
private String LastName;
// define data fields

public Name( String name1 , String name2 )
    {
    FirstName = name1;
    LastName = name2;
    }
// constructor

public String GetFirstName()
    {
    return FirstName;
    }
// get first name

public String GetLastName()
    {
    return LastName;
    }
// last name getter

public void SetFirstName( String name1 )
    {
    FirstName = name1;
    }
// first name setter

public void SetLastName( String name2 )
    {
    LastName = name2;
    }
// last name setter
}
```

Inevitably, working with the Employee class seems to produce this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Employee.GetName1(Employee.java:22)
at EmployeeTest.main(EmployeeTest.java:16)
```

Can it be identified, what I am doing wrong with the aggregation of classes?

Comment: Why is that when debugging a program people don't think to use their debugger?  This would be trivial to check and fix that way.

Answer (score 2):

IN `Employee` contructor `name` is local variable.

`Name name = new Name( name1 , name2 );`

Change it to :

`name = new Name( name1 , name2 );`

So that instance variable `name` will be initialized

Answer (score 1):

Remove the class name here :

```
Name name = new Name( name1 , name2 );
```

Because you are not setting the *name* variable of your class here, you are just recreating a new one, so the other one remains null.

So it should read :

```
name = new Name( name1 , name2 );
```

The same problem exists for *address* and *date* variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have this error `java.lang.NullPointerException` because you should create an istance of `Name` in contructor of `Employee` like:

```
    public Employee(String name1, String name2, String street, String city,
        String state, String zip, int month, int day, int year) {
     name = new Name(name1, name2);
```

Not:

```
    public Employee(String name1, String name2, String street, String city,
        String state, String zip, int month, int day, int year) {
     Name name = new Name(name1, name2);
```